# How to prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}(x)dx=0$?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}(x)dx=0$$

First I tried by recurrence relation

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{n}(x)dx=I_n=\frac{n-1}{n} I_{n-2}$$

Than $I_n$ is cauchy sequence because $\frac{n-1}{n}<1$
So it's bounded and converge.

But how to prove limit is 0?

Futhermore, It is possible that prove without using recurrence relation?

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3557576/72031) which is based on your recurrence relation.

Answer (score 1):

This is an immediate consequence of DCT (Dominated Convergence Theorem).

Ref . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem

Proof without using DCT. Let $\epsilon >0$. Note that $\int_{\pi /2-\epsilon}^{\pi/2} \sin^{n} x dx \leq \int_{\pi /2-\epsilon}^{\pi/2} 1 dx=\epsilon$.  Now consider $\int_0^{\pi /2-\epsilon} \sin x^{n} dx$. Observe that the supremum of $\sin x$ on $[0,\pi /2-\epsilon]$ is a number $r$ less than $1$. Hence $\int_0^{\pi /2-\epsilon} \sin x^{n} dx \leq r^{n} (\pi /2) \to 0$. Now just add the two integrals.

Comment: But, How to integrate $\sin^{\infty}=1 (x=frac{\pi}{2}),0((x!=frac{\pi}{2})$

Comment: $\sin^{n} x \to 0$ for every $x$ and $|\sin x| \leq 1$. That is all the information you need to apply DCT.  @user745082

Comment: @user745082 I have added an elemenatary proof which avoids DCT.